# How do I change a CSS Style attribute once a condition is met? PHP, JS, CSS

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

Good Day!

I am having a difficulty when it comes to showing a pop-up box in my webpage. I would like to show it when it meets a certain condition inside my php code, which is under the `Condition.php`. I have included the js file, which removes a certain class to make the box visible. How would I execute the JS code inside the `Condition.php` when it meets a certain condition?

Here are my codes:

**Condition.php**

```
<?php
    // Defined variables and additional codes section
    if (strlen($str) == 4) {
        // Show the popup box
    }
    // Additional Codes
?>
```

**ConfirmCheck.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#confirm').click(function () {
        $('.popup').removeClass("hide");
    });
});
```

**Check.php**

```
<form class="frm" action="Condition.php" method="POST">
    // Additional Codes here
    <input type="submit" name="checkOutBtn" value="CONFIRM" id="confirm">
</form>

<?php include 'box.php';?>
<script src='ConfirmCheck.js'></script>
```

**Box.php**

```
<div class="popup hide" id="popupID">
    <div class="box">
            <div class="form">
                <h1>SUCCESS!</h1>
                <form action="home.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p class="paragraph">
                            Your order has been successfully placed!
                        </p>
                        <button class="homepageBtn" onclick="home.php">GO TO THE HOME PAGE</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you need to show the popup directly from php or do you want to block the popup when confirm button is clicked but some condition in php are false?

Comment: @Stefino76 I would like to show the popup box when the button is clicked and at the same time if a certain condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require simply put the `if` condition inside `box.php` and remove `condition.php` as it serves no purpose having an entire PHP page for a single condition.

box.php

```html
<div class="popup <? if (strlen($str) != 4) { ?>hide<? } ?>" id="popupID">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="form">
      <h1>SUCCESS!</h1>
      <form action="home.php">
        <div class="form-group">
          <p class="paragraph">
            Your order has been successfully placed!
          </p>
          <button class="homepageBtn" onclick="home.php">GO TO THE HOME PAGE</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: will that remove the hide class of the div as well?

Comment: The `hide` class will only be shown in the page then `strlen($str)` is not `4`.

Comment: Is nested conditional statement also applicable for that method?

Comment: Yes, as that determines whether or not the `hide` class should be added. It's in the first line of the example above

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you've set the action of your form to `Condition.php` but included the box design and code on `check.php`.

Note that `#confirm` is and input of type submit so after its pressed it will redirect you to the page specified at the action of the form.

I can suggest two possible fixes to that:

1. [least suggested] display the confirmation box on the `Condition.php` page
2. [most suggested] use AJAX!

The first fix requires you to move the markup and styles for box to the `Condition.php` file and design a whole confirmation/post action page

The second fix is better because by sending the Data to the server using AJAX you're not only going to stay on the same page (`check.php`) but you can also sort of hide the address to `Condition.php` which is supposed to be a backend file(from what i understood)

The structure should look something like this:

**check.php:**

```
<div class="frm">
    // Additional Codes here
    <buttin name="checkOutBtn" id="confirm">CONFIRMM</button>
</form>

<?php include 'box.php';?>
<script src='ConfirmCheck.js'></script>
```

**ConfirmCheck.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#confirm').click(function () {
        // code to get all of your fields and put them in a js object: FDATA
        $.ajax({type:'POST', url:'Condition.php', data: FDATA,
        success:function(){
             $('.popup').removeClass("hide");
        }});
    });
});
```

**Condition.php:**

```php
<?php
    // Defined variables and additional codes section
    if (strlen($str) == 4) { //success
        echo "success message";
    }else{ // failed
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
        die("bad request");
    }
    // Additional Codes
?>
```

The request goes back and forth between `check.php` and `Condition.php` in the background and your code gets notified through a callback whether or not to show the box.

Comment: If I choose the first fix, I will just implement a separate webpage instead of a pop-up box. Did I get it correctly?

Comment: yes pretty much. The way you implemented it also isn't going to work as a pop up(php executes on server side and the results will be sent to the page in the end. you dont use php to make dynamic front end features you use javascript). to make the results display as a pop up you need to stay on the same page and for that you need to send the request in the background and for that you need Ajax(forms with specified action take you to another page) @ChrisJay106